# Simple makefile for C++

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I am having some trouble with a programing assignment for a CS class. We were introduced to makefiles this week, but it was barely touched upon. The goal is to write a program to calculate the average and summation of user provided doubles. The program works fine with g++, but I am having issues with the makefiles.

I am working with 3 cpp files: main.cpp, average.cpp, summation.cpp.
And 2 header files: average.h and summation.h

Here is one make file I have tried:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic-errors -g

SRCS = summation.cpp average.cpp main.cpp 
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}
HEADERS = summation.h average.h

MAIN = myprog

all: ${MAIN}
    @echo   Simple compilter named myprog has been compiled

${MAIN}: ${OBJS} ${HEADERS}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${MAIN} ${OBJS}

.cpp.o:
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

clean:
    ${RM} ${PROGS} ${OBJS} *.o *~
```

Errors:
  main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `avg(double*, int)'
  main.cpp:32: undefined reference to`sum(double*, int)'

If I run the command
    g++ main.cpp summation.cpp average.cpp -o main
Then it will compile without any issues.

I'm not sure if I have something out of order, or if I am missing something. Looking around I've found a lot of info, but it seems to be over my head.

Comment: You should also see the compiler command make ran that generated the error. What was it?

Comment: define CXX as "echo g++", then run and enjoy the hint

Comment: Why `{OBJS}` is mentioned twice: `${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${MAIN} ${OBJS}`? I think correct is `${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${MAIN}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two problems here.

First, the ordering `SRCS = summation.cpp average.cpp main.cpp`. This causes the `.o` to be provided to g++ in the order `summation.o average.o main.o` which causes the undefined error. You want to provide them in the order `main.o summation.o average.o`, hence SRCS should be `SRCS =  main.cpp summation.cpp average.cpp`.

Second, in the line:

```
${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${MAIN} ${OBJS}
```

The second `${OBJS}` is not needed.
Try the following:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic-errors -g

SRCS =  main.cpp summation.cpp average.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}
HEADERS = summation.h average.h

MAIN = myprog

all: ${MAIN}
        @echo   Simple compilter named myprog has been compiled

${MAIN}: ${OBJS}
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${MAIN}

.cpp.o:
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

clean:
        ${RM} ${PROGS} ${OBJS} *.o *~.
```